# UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How can I animate `UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash` when the user selects the button?

When the user selects the image for deletion, the image is coming to the trash button.

This effect is seen within the iPhone/iPad Album application.

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly this is done using the suck effect animation.  But it happens to be an undocumented part of the api so would likely be rejected in the app store.  Someone has created a class with a similar effect using opengl that maybe you could use:

https://github.com/rmd6502/GenieGL

Comment: the code to do it with the private api:
[UIView beginAnimations:@"suck" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:103 forView:myViewContainer cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationPosition:CGPointMake(12, 345)];
[myView removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];